# how to avoid the cursor statement to execute if no records are retunred

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, fetch

I have a nested cursor whose select statement sometimes returns 0 records.

The cursor executes an insert statement.

I'd expect that the insert statement is not executed if the query returns 0 records. But it is executed anyway. Could you suggset a way to avoid this?

```
    declare  nested_cursor CURSOR 
    FOR 
    SELECT MyRECORD 

    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyRECORD = @ID -- @ID is a variable defined in the main cursor
    -- for some values of @iD ht above select statement may return zero records
    OPEN nested_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM nested_cursor INTO @NestedID
    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
    BEGIN  


        INSERT STATEMENT  -- HERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM , why this executes?                 
        FETCH NEXT FROM nested_cursor INTO @NestedID
    END
    CLOSE nested_cursor
    DEALLOCATE nested_cursor
```

UPDATE: I found a workaround by checking if @NestedId is null just before the INSERT statement.

WHat do you suggest? to add this check in

```
WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0) and (@NestedID is not null)
```

or there is a better technique?

Comment: In my exprience I have always managed to write the sql I need without using a cursor. I'd suggest this would be relatively easy in your case and it would also resolve the problem you have here. You are effectively doing an "insert statement (myrecord) select myrecord from mytable where myrecord = @id "

Comment: Why even use a cursor for this at all??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a comment but, will redo the select in the answer so that I can use the code formatting to make it clearer.

```
insert statement (myrecord) 
select myrecord 
from mytable where myrecord = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be working as you've shown it. And as others have said, a cursor seems unnecessary.

You might try checking [@@CURSOR_ROWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176044.aspx) after your OPEN statement. As an alternative, maybe it is returning rows, but unexpectedly, the MyRecord column is null, or some other unexpected value?